# How to update column value after some time interval

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to update a particular column value from Y to N after every 3 minutes.

Table Structure

```
`u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(11) NOT NULL
```

How can i change status N after 3 mins for each row in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something called [EVENTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) in MySQL.

You may try following steps to achieve.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -- enable event scheduler.
SELECT @@event_scheduler;  -- check whether event scheduler is ON/OFF
CREATE EVENT e_store_ts  -- create your event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 180 SECOND  -- run every 180 secs (3 Min)
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.youtable set mycolumn='N' -- update this table
```

To see the events that created

```
 SHOW EVENTS;
```

For more detail : [Schedule SQL Query to execute on specific time interval](https://apptech-solution.blogspot.in/2016/08/schedule-sql-query-to-execute-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a corn job to run every 3 minutes, which is the most standard way of doing repetitive work.
Refer [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) which gives an easy explanation about how to create corn job.

The corn expression to run every 3 minutes is: 0 0/3 * 1/1 * ? *